# Sumar valores de un array php

Tags: php

Necesito hacer la suma de unos valores de un array que recojo en un formulario en php y no consigo hacerlo.

El resultado que se recoge por el formulario en la variable sería algo así:  "valor1, valor2, valor3".

Pero con la función `array_sum` de php no funciona

Os dejo el código a ver si alguien me ayuda

```html
$sumtfs=((isset($_POST['tfs']) && is_array($_POST['tfs'])) ? implode(', ', $_POST['tfs']) : '');

$total = array_sum($sumtfs);
```

Comment: podrías añadir en tu código antes de `$total` un `print_r($sumtfs);` y añadir en la descripcion lo que sale

Comment: ¿Qué error te da? Sería bueno que nos mostrases el contenido de la variable `$sumtfs` y un ejemplo de los datos que te llegan por `$_POST`, sin los datos de entrada que estás usando es difícil saber el problema que puedes tener.

Comment: @David haciendo el print_r  me sale por ejemplo 10, 20, 30

Comment: @phpMyGuel los datos llegan segun lo que seleccionas pero son números enteros como los del anterior comentario. He revisado y guarda la array pero el fallo esta en que no la suma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array_sum` espera un array, pero lo que estás haciendo con `implode` es formar un string con el array.

Quizá esto te funcione, aquí estoy suponiendo que $_POST['tfs'] es un array, o es un string con los números separados por comas, pero no sé si son suposiciones correctas ya que no hay datos sobre esa variable en tu pregunta.

```php
$total = 0;
if (isset($_POST['tfs'])) {

    // Si $_POST['tfs'] ya es un array, ejecutamos array_sum en él.
    if (is_array($_POST['tfs'])) {
        $total = array_sum($_POST['tfs']);
    }

    // Si no, suponemos que es un string, lo separamos por comas (explode) y sumamos sobre el array generado.
    else {
        $total = array_sum(explode(',', $_POST['tfs]));
    }
}
```

En tu código lo que haces es generar un string separado por comas a partir de un array, y eso no es lo que quieres:

```php
// Este es tu código
// Si $_POST['tfs'] es un array, haces implode (que genera un string), si no devuelves ''
$sumtfs=((isset($_POST['tfs']) && is_array($_POST['tfs'])) ? implode(', ', $_POST['tfs']) : '');
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funciono perfecto

Comment: @Juanperez me alegro :-), deberías aceptar la respuesta para que no quede abierta.